# What are some alternative launcher programs for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, launcher

Quicksilver on the Mac is crashing all the time. QSB or Google Desktop Search are both slow enough to be unusable. What are the alternatives?

Comment: you have Quicksilver crashing constantly? Weird. I've never had it crash once in the nearly one year I've been running it.

Answer (score 4):

Stick with what Steve Jobs gave you: Spotlight Search. `Apple + Space` and type away!

Answer (score 3):

[LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html).  Very fast and stable.

Answer (score 2):

I consider [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) to be the up-to-date, highly functional, maintained version of Quicksilver. It seems a lot snappier, and I've been using it in place of Quicksilver since I found out about it. Try it out!

Answer (score 1):

I use [Namely](http://amarsagoo.info/namely/) -- it is probably the most basic launcher, but that is exactly what I want.

Comment: most basic, fastest, lightest-weight and best. Very very smart, too

Answer (score 0):

[Overflow](http://stuntsoftware.com/overflow/)'s Pretty nice, I use it, plus i got it for free from Macheist :>

Answer (score 0):

Your timing couldn't be more perfect:

**This article came out on June 1st and is literally called, "[Nine Great Launchers to Speed up Your Workflow](http://smokingapples.com/software/reviews/9-lauchers-to-put-your-mac-at-your-fingertips/)"**